# embedding subview in navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, view, uinavigationcontroller, containers

this is my first post on Stackoverflow. I'm new to iOS development and I searched and tried a lot (for over two days), but I'm really stuck to something that should be really simple to make.

I have a main view (full size iPhone view). Inside that view I want a smaller size subview (for example 290 x 400). This subview must be embedded in a navigation controller. In other words: I want a working navigation bar at the top of this subview.

I have built this in Storyboards using a container view. No problem there. However, I want to do this in code only. I successfully made a navigation controller based app in code. I also successfully coded an app with a child view controller. The problem seems to be combining those.

When I try to load the navigationcontroller in one of the child view controllers, the app crashes and says that the SubView view controller must have the Container view controller as a parent, but it has UINavigationcontroller as a parent now.

After that I tried to load the navigationcontroller directly in the subview, like this:

```
SubViewVC *subviewcontroller = [[SubVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubVC" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subviewcontroller];

[navController setView:subviewcontroller.view];

[self.view addSubview:subviewcontroller.view];
```

However, now I get a crash that says that a view can only be associated with one controller at a time. The subview is associated with SubViewVC. This must be cleared before associating it with UINavigationcontroller.

I understand the problem, but don't know how to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing several things incorrectly. First, you don't need to set the navigation controller's  view, that's already done, by instantiating it with a root view controller. Secondly, you should be adding navController's view to your view, not subviewcontroller's view. You also, should be adding navController as a child, and setting the frame of its view. Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SubViewVC *subviewcontroller = [[SubViewVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subviewcontroller];
    [self addChildViewController:nav];
    [nav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    nav.view.frame = CGRectMake(15, 20, 290, 400);
    [self.view addSubview:nav.view];
}
```

Comment: rdelmar, you are todays hero. Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.